# React native, Component not showing anything on device, but works fine on browser

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I was building my application on browser and it works completely fine, but when I tried to run it on my phone nothing were showing. This is how it looks like on my browser

[image: on browser]

but on my phone I got nothing

[image]

here're my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.4",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1", <-- I didn't even use this I always use "react-native"
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-router-native": "^6.2.1"
  }
```

I also checked the logs on browser and nothing were showing.

the code

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HomePage extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 100}}>Tested application</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Homepage;
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of the component?

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Component looks fine, what does the console says?

Comment: It seems that there's an issue with the parent component. This component works well for each platform. https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/a7937d